# Angular: Include third party dependency in custom angular library

Tags: angular, commonjs, umd, npm-package, angular-package-format

I am trying to create a library as npm package using `ng generate library ts-utils` command

This library use of a dependency called [memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee), where we include the library and its respective [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/memoizee) in the `peerDependencies` section of the library.

**NOTE:** nowhere else in my package do I reference these dependencies only in package.json

```
{
  "name": "@heanfig/ts-utils",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Plugin for TypeScript to support custom decorators and functions",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.0",
    "@types/memoizee": "^0.4.7",
    "memoizee": "^0.4.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

When I try to generate the library and publish it to npmjs it does not generate any problems,

When I try to use it by installing it in the project that needs it, it generates a warning similar to this:

```
Warning: /Users/hermanfigueroaidarraga/Desktop/@hf/ts-utils-demo/dist/ts-utils/fesm2015/heanfig-ts-utils.mjs depends on 'memoizee'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Additionally it tells me that `memoizee` is `undefined`, and when I go to check in the project where I installed the dependency, inside the `node_modules` folder there is both **memoizee** and its **types**

[image]

[image]

Apparently there is a module, commonJS or umd types error but the exact cause of this error cannot be determined because my package does not find the dependency knowing that it is correctly installed in the node_modules directory with its respective types

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Not really a solution for you, but in our project we publish a package to a private npm repo and had the same error... I ended up just manually putting the `peerDependency` as a `dependency` in the consuming application and that resolves this..... Something about certain version of npm not installing `peerDependencies` by default.

Comment: @Zze FYI, Node version 16+ (And its corresponding NPM versions) install `peerDependencies` by default. But in versions before that, it expects you to install `peerDependencies` by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memoizee` and its types should go into `dependencies` section for your library.

peer dependancies are intended for extension by plugin (e.g. the `@angular/...` dependencies, as they are target for extension) see the documentation here https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/